# Prevent browser from repeating long post requests

Tags: ajax, http, browser

According to the HTTP 1.1 spec, [browsers should retry a request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.4) if they pass a certain time limit or if an error response is received. POST requests are no exception.

Occasionally, slow connections combined with a processor heavy request can cause an ajax POST request to time out, and the browser will fire a second POST request with the same data. This leads to unexpected and erroneous behaviors. Is there any way to prevent that browser timeout from triggering and firing a second POST request?

Comment: I think this is now covered by [RFC 7230, section 6.3.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.1). And no, I do not believe this can be controlled through the server.

Comment: @DaSourcerer, not via server, but client side javascript would be great.

Comment: Beyond [`XMLHttpRequest.timeout`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-timeout-attribute) you mean? I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my understanding you can't restrict the client to stop automatic retries.
The best option is to handle the identical requests in the server side by using unique GUID's.
https://blogs.oracle.com/ravello/beware-http-requests-automatic-retries/comment-submitted?cid=b956dee8-7352-4d88-ad40-71ff9fd1eb53